# Conexão Sql Server Banco .MDF não funciona C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Minha aplicação da erro quando tento executar em outra máquina, só que nessa máquina não tenho nada do sql server instalado, o que preciso para rodar minha aplicação em qualquer pc?

Segue o erro:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar Servidor/Instância Especificada)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   em System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   em WindowsFormsApp1.formLogin.acessar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Sisgemp\formLogin.cs:linha 44
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   em System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
```

Comment: Poderia acrescentar a string de conexão que utilizou? É necessário que o software cliente do SQL Server esteja instalado no computador onde a aplicação será executada.

Comment: qual seria o  software cliente do SQL Server? Tem algum link para download?

Comment: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Sisgemp\Sisgemp.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o programa está esperando a base (arquivo mdf) em um local na máquina onde está sendo executado o programa.

Para que o programa seja executado de *qualquer máquina*, é necessário que o banco seja acessível por *qualquer máquina*.

Para isso, você deve instalar o servidor SQL Server, que é proprietário da Microsoft (e não é gratuito) : https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: A edição Express do SQL Server é gratuita.